# Adding Recessed Lighting to room with ceiling fan and a 4 way switch?

Tags: wiring, lighting, ceiling-fan, dimmer-switch

I am installing recessed lighting. There is currently a ceiling fan with a light already installed on the ceiling I am installing the lights. 3 switches all control power to the ceiling fan.

My goal is to have one dimmer switch for the recessed lighting and then one switch for the new fan I will install that doesn't have a light.

I am okay getting rid of the 4 way switch.

Here is a diagram of my current set up.

https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/4_way_switch_diagram.html

Comment: What controls power to the current light kit? The pull chains?

Comment: Also, how many watts of recessed lighting are you throwing in?

Comment: Are you saying you want to eliminate the 3-ways and 4-way? We need to know specifically what you want to do. You should edit your question to specify what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the 4 way switches come in handy for controlling it from different spots but here are some ways you can do. you could make the recessed lights be on the 4 way switch system and replace the 3 toggles with dimmers and run an extra hot wire for the fan iself. Or you could make the neutral wire running from the switch box directly to the fan box as a hot wire tape ot black and put the fan neutral to ground and make the new hot run the fan unless it;s code voilation but i tried it myself it worked fine. and if you dont want the 4 way switch you can replace the extras with a coverplate. and the extra wires can be used for the fan and one for light. good luck.